# Dojo vs jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, dojo

With jQueryMobile I came to the point where I have to think about using another gui-framework.

E.g.: I'd like to have list-items to be swiped away from the list, to be deleted. The distance the list-items is swiped out should be the distance my finger moves the item. It shouldn't be automated. Well it should, when I release the finger, to finally remove it. jQm doesn't have approtpriated swipe-events for this. Furthermore jqm is extremely slow recognizing events.

I just found the dojo-framework. It seems to have better touch-events and it offers mvc. I'd like to check it out, but I don't have much time at the moment, so I'm depending on your opinions.

Now I'd like to ask a few questions:

1. Would it be possible to use swipe-events on list-items, like native applications to support?
2. Does anyone know if it'd have disatvantages to use dojo instead of jqm?
3. Is dojo using require.js?

Thx for your advises :)

Answer (score 1):

**Would it be possible to use swipe-events on list-items, like native applications to support?**

Yes, Yes, Yes.

using a combination of JQM swipe events and some JQ.

if you search that same question on Stack overflow you'll probably get the answer.

**Does anyone know if it'd have disadvantages to use dojo instead of jqm?**

well think about this way. Do you think JQM that is releasing new versions every 6 months or so will ever stop to do so. And with each version, there's lots of improvements and Addon features. Depends whats your flavor. If you know JQM well, stick with it. If its alien to you, and you find Dojo easier to use then work with that.

**Is dojo using require.js?**

i never heard of dojo. but now that you mentioned it ill have a look.
have you checked the docs on requires js compatibility with whats out here? perhaps is a universal plugging.

ps. I just checked some Dojo demos. Looks Good.

Answer (score 1):

### Would it be possible to use swipe-events on list-items, like native applications to support?

Dojo provides several synthetic events (events that are calculated based upon other native events like `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend`, ..). You can find those at the [`dojox/gesture`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/gesture.html) module. It provides synthetic events like tap and swipe.

If the list item widget (`dojox/mobile/ListItem`) doesn't support it, that doesn't mean it's impossible. Dojo allows module inheritance and extending modules/widgets so it should be possible to implement that feature yourself.

---

### Does anyone know if it'd have disatvantages to use dojo instead of jqm?

The second question you ask is primary opinion based*, but you cannot actually compare the two. While Dojo indeed has a mobile framework (`dojox/mobile`) like jQuery has with jQuery mobile, Dojo also has a lot of extra stuff (like you mentioned **mvc**) which means you need third party frameworks to do the same thing with jQuery (for example by using AngularJS).

Dojo's community is smaller than the jQuery community, so that means it might be harder to find support, tutorials and guides.

Dojo mobile is actively developed by the community and IBM also has also made a lot of improvements because they're using this in a product of their own called IBM Worklight.

*(* So be careful if you don't want your question to be closed)*

---

### Is dojo using require.js?

The idea of require.js is derived from the Dojo AMD loader, however, Dojo picked the path to support backwards compatibility and so James Burke (Dojo developer and now Require.js lead) created his own framework based upon those concepts. So no, Dojo doesn't use require.js though they're very similar because they're based upon the same idea.

However, Require.js should be able to support Dojo. So you should be able to use require.js in stead of the Dojo AMD loader if you want to do that.

Comment: I think you have that sort of backwards.  AMD and RequireJS came first, then Dojo's loader and builder were updated to adopt the AMD format in 1.7.  The author of Dojo's updated loader was pretty involved in the AMD discussion group for a while though.  James Burke, author of RequireJS, also wrote the original (non-AMD) Dojo loader.

Comment: O, I always thought the idea of rewriting the module loader started within the Dojo community but because it still has to support backward compatibility James decided to improve it even further and create Require.js.

Comment: I think there is some truth to that.  Just didn't want people thinking that RequireJS was like, forked from Dojo's AMD loader or something.  Anyway, more importantly, you are right that Dojo should be able to cooperate with other AMD loaders.  There were some hiccups along the way which have been resolved in more recent versions of Dojo.